# Google Spreadsheet script to color rows containing a certain word and automatically move the row to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having problems with creating a google spreadsheet script that will color rows with certain words in it, then copying those rows to another spreadsheet.

For example, I want to color a row that has the word "banana" blue, then have a copy of that row in spreadsheet A.

Then color a row that has the word "apple" green, then have a copy of that row in spreadsheet B.

And so on.

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google spreadsheet set row background color based on note](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342762/google-spreadsheet-set-row-background-color-based-on-note)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider your question in two parts, you'll find that there are already examples here that address them. 
For your solution, you could adapt the code from those answers.

Previous questions about *setting the color of a row according to content*:

- [Format row color based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105563/format-row-color-based-on-cell-value)
- [google spreadsheet set row background color based on note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342762/google-spreadsheet-set-row-background-color-based-on-note)

Previous question about *copying rows containing specific colors* to specific spreadsheets:

- [Google Spreadsheets: Find a conditionally formatted colour and copy row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257229/google-spreadsheets-find-a-conditionally-formatted-colour-and-copy-row/15257672#15257672)

---

Search results:

StackOverflow supports rich searching within its database - if you do any search, the result page will include an `Advanced Search Tips` link, that shows you the operators available. You can learn much more on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), if you're so inclined.

Here are a couple of the searches used to come up with the examples in this answer.

- `[google-apps-script] +color +row +sheet is:question` [Results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20%2bcolor%20%2brow%20%2bsheet%20is:question)
- `[google-apps-script] +color +row +sheet +copy` [Results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20%2bcolor%20%2brow%20%2bsheet%20%2bcopy)